# Magento Css Versioning

Tags: css, magento, versioning

wondering if anyone has done/knows how to complete this functionality: 
http://code.marksserver.co.uk/magento/css-magento/magento-add-css-versioning/1045/

i have implemented it within my head.php file - and im seeing the amended css file name with the ?version=1.0.0 at the end - but each time i change and save my css file the version number is not changing...

am i missing the boat completely and i need to be changing something more?  thanks for the help! - chris

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for; http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/automatisches-versionieren-von-javascript-und-css-dateien-in-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution you linked to requires you to manually change the version number to add to the url.

I put together something that uses the default css merging in Magento, but appends the timestamp of the most recently modified file the the filename.

http://smith-web.net/2013/02/09/magento-css-auto-versioning/

It sounds similar to the one linked to from Fabrizo above, I didn't download his code from the blog post, but found his git repository for it, and it seems to have been updated since the blog post above. Looks like he added CDN support, and some other features since that post, so you may want to check that out as well. https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_JsCssTstamp